# adding regular expression jquery

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, jquery-validate

hi i am using jquery validation plugin , i want to add a validation to my `price` field ,

the only available are `numbers 0-9` , `comma` , `dot`

```
1000
1000.00
1,000.00
```

should be available please help . this is my function

```
    var x=$("#form").validate({                     

        rules: {
            price: {
                custom_number: true
            }
        },

        messages: {

        }

    }); 

$.validator.addMethod("custom_number", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || value === "NA" ||
        value.match(/^[0-9,\+-]+$/);
}, "Please enter a valid number");
```

i want to add my expression here `value.match(/^[0-9,\+-]+$/)`

thanks...............................

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the RegExp that should work:

```
^[1-9]\d{0,2}(?:\d+|(?:,\d{3})*)(?:\.\d{2})?$
```

[Here](http://regexr.com?2uu18) you can test it against various strings.

Comment: The first group should be `\d` (`[0-9]`) to match numbers like `0.01` and so on, right?

Comment: @Mikulas: But then it would match 0,000. As it stands it misses anything > 9,999.99 when comma is included.

Comment: @MikulasDite But in this case it also will match 000,111 for example, not sure is it a problem or not.

Comment: @bjornd . Mikulas Dite is correct , it is not working for numbers like 0.01 . please help

Comment: @KanishkaPanamaldeniya If several leading zeros is not a problem you can use ^\d{0,2}(?:\d+|(?:,\d{3})*)(?:\.\d{2})?$.

Answer (score 0):

This one should do it:

```
value.match(/^[0-9,.]+$/);
```

Comment: mm nop . i am looking for an answer like this , but this is not checking for commas http://www.codingforums.com/archive/index.php/t-85204.html

Answer (score 0):

Believe it or not, this behemoth seems to work, and it permits the dollar sign.

```
^\$?([1-9]{1}[0-9]{0,2}(\,[0-9]{3})*(\.[0-9]{0,2})?|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{0,}(\.[0-9]{0,2})?|0(\.[0-9]{0,2})?|(\.[0-9]{1,2})?)$
```

I *borrowed* it from [RegExLib.com](http://regexlib.com/DisplayPatterns.aspx?cattabindex=2&categoryId=3&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1). If this regex doesn’t work for you, perhaps one of the others will.